# How to configure AutoMapper 9.0 in IIS hosted WCF application

Tags: wcf, thread-safety, automapper, .net-4.7.2, automapper-9

I want to use AutoMapper 9.0 in a WCF project containing several services that will be hosted in IIS. I've only found one other related SO question but its dealing with a 10 year old version of AutoMapper and is not asking the same question. Its answer is similar to the top hits on Google which suggest using a `ServiceBehavior` but that doesn't seem applicable when I want multiple services to use the same mapper. The defense rests.

In a web project, you might create a static `MapperConfiguration` in the `Global.asax` when the application starts, but WCF doesn't have a `Global.asax`. It looks like there are a few options for executing initialization code in WCF:

1. Include an `AppInitialize()` method in the App_Code folder. This will be dynamically compiled at runtime and people have complained that it can have missing reference issues in IIS so I'm not confident `AutoMapper` or its dependencies will be found once deployed to IIS.
2. Create a custom `ServiceHost`. This seems like it would execute once when the application starts, but also looks like it ignores the web.config configuration, which I don't want.
3. Use the [`Configure` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/configuring-wcf-services-in-code) per service. This has the same drawback as #2 and also I become concerned with thread safety (as in the `ServiceBehavior` approach) since two services could try to initialize the `MapperConfiguration` at once.

I considered just creating a class with a static property that would create a static `MapperConfiguration` or `IMapper` instance if it was not already created, but as in #3, I'm worried this may not be thread safe. Maybe if I did something like this?

```
public static class MapperConfig
{
    private static IMapper _modelMapper;
    private static readonly object _mapperLocker = new object();

    public static IMapper ModelMapper
    {
        get
        {
            lock(_mapperLocker)
            {
                if (_modelMapper == null)
                {
                    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.AddProfile(new MappingProfile1()));
                    _modelMapper = config.CreateMapper();
                }
            }

            return _modelMapper;
        }
    }
}
```

Where two services may call `ModelMapper` simultaneously. Another downside of this is the first request to any service will have to wait for the mapping to compile, but I'm not sure I can get away from that. I definitely don't want it compiling the mappings per call and would prefer not to even have to do it per service. Can you advise on the thread safety of `MapperConfiguration` and the best way to use it in IIS-hosted WCF?

Comment: You should have DI in your services. People did this before.

Comment: That seems like an additional feature that will have to solve the same problems

Comment: They are already solved. There is documentation and there are many examples with AM and DI.